# Google Cloud Function abruptly stops without errors!

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, request, google-cloud-functions

**Problem**
My cloud function abruptly stops in the 4th iteration of a **finite** 12 iteration loop.

I have a script where I request form data from an external server. I do this for each individual form. I store the data in a temporary df and thereafter append this temporary df to a final df.

However, the function just stops working after the 4th loop. I have tried to log the complete process but I can't find any error messages. I added custom logs to see where it stops inside the loop. In my local environment the script works flawlessly. Therefore, it must be something wrong on Google's side. I have also tried to increase the timeout, gigabyte storage and so on. Nothing works. The script should not take longer than 20 seconds to complete.

[Here is the code of the loop that abruptly stops.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9wX.png)

Does somebody have a solution on how to better debug this problem?
[Here you see the logs of the loop and how it abruptly stops after the 4th iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Ko4.png)